# Using pgffor and line breaks inside math environments

Tags: amsmath, pgffor

Today I decided to try to typeset a humorous list enumerating all 7! valid iterated integrals for a 7-dimensional integral (It takes 361 pages in the version that does compile) but I'm running into very unhelpful errors when I try to add the last bit of polish. I learned how to use pgffor to generate the permutations, but trying to run my code with nice alignments breaks it.

Since the 7 variable code is a bit unwieldy, I've reproduced the two-variable case here. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!d}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \iint_B f(x, y)
  \foreach \a/\b/\x in {a/b/x, c/d/y}
  \foreach \c/\d/\y in {a/b/x, c/d/y}
           {
             \ifx \y \x \else
             = \int_\a^\b \int_\c^\d f(x, y) \diff\x \diff\y
             \fi
           }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But of course it's all on one line.
If I add `\\` to the end of `\int_\a^\b \int_\c^\d f(x, y) \diff\x \diff\y`, it doesn't actually break the lines since `equation` doesn't support multiline equations. Here's where things get confusing for me:

If I change the environment to `multline` I get a pile of errors starting with

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

If I change the environment to AMSMath's `align` then I get the rather similar looking

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

If I add a `&` for alignment without the line breaks (to prevent the other error) then I get the following error:

```
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 16.
```

How can I use the combination of pgffor, amsmath's `align` environment, and alignment/linebreak commands?
More generally, why doesn't pgffor play nice with these macros?

Comment: It is not really anything to do with `pgffor`. Try, for example, `\begin{gather*}
  {%
 ij kl\\
  }
\end{gather*}`.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is the structural equivalent of something like `\begin{tabular}{c} {some stuff\\}\end{tabular}`.  These environments are essentially like sophisticated `array` or `tabular` environments: the TeX code is using the stuff used to set out tab-separated material. And you can't start a group on one row and end it on a later one, which is what you are trying to do here. As I say, I think the `pgffor` is a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty hard to control the expanding order while there are table-like environment and for-structure involved. However, one can first write the contents to a separated file and then input it immediately. By doing so the expanding order is clear.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,newfile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!d}
\newoutputstream{factorial}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.factorial}{factorial}
    \addtostream{factorial}{
        \iint_B f(x, y)
    }
    \foreach \a/\b/\x in {a/b/x, c/d/y}{
        \foreach \c/\d/\y in {a/b/x, c/d/y}{
            \ifx \y \x \else
                \addtostream{factorial}{
                    = \protect\int_\a^\b \protect\int_\c^\d f(x, y) \diff\x \diff\y \\
                }
            \fi
        }
    }
\closeoutputstream{factorial}

\begin{align*}
    \input{\jobname.factorial}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```